# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, консоль

Google Console показывает ошибку:

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.

Помогите разобраться как исправить эту ошибку.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2583)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2665)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1499)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5765)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:806)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:696)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:539)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:423)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:374)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
  at st.hromlist.viktortsoi.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:155)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6309)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1113)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2530)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:645)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:764)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:704)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:835)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:798)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:838)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:798)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude (LayoutInflater.java:971)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:831)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:798)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:515)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Native Method)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable (TypedArray.java:867)
  at android.view.View.<init> (View.java:4001)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init> (ViewGroup.java:599)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init> (FrameLayout.java:115)
  at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.<init> (HorizontalScrollView.java:159)
  at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.<init> (HorizontalScrollView.java:154)
  at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.<init> (TabLayout.java:439)
  at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.<init> (TabLayout.java:435)
```

Строка   at st.hromlist.viktortsoi.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:155) в коде ссылается на setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings, false);
    LoadSettings.loadSettings(this);
    if (bundle == null) {
        checkFistRunApp();
        quotes = getStringQuotes();
    } else {
        this.bundle = bundle;
        quotes = bundle.getString(QUOTES);
    }
    setTheme(themeId);
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)); 
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_coordinator_layout);

    final ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            float slideX = drawerView.getWidth() * slideOffset;
            coordinatorLayout.setTranslationX(slideX);
        }
    };

    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.group_nav_bar_one, false, false);

    buttonDisableAds = findViewById(R.id.button_disable_ads);
    backgroundButtonDisableAds = findViewById(R.id.backgoutd_button_disable_ads);

    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = headerView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_nav_header);
    linearLayout.setPadding(0, paddingTop(), 0, 0);
    navHeaderTitle = headerView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_nav_header_title);
    navHeaderSubtitle = headerView.findViewById(R.id.test_view_nav_header_subtitle);
    navHeaderSubtitle.setText(quotes);
    createListenerFingering();

    listSongsFragment = new ListSongsFragment();
    favoritesFragment = new FavoritesFragment();

    SectionPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new SectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    mBillingClient();

    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(mTabListener);

    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.colorBackground, typedValue, true);
    adMobColorBackground = typedValue.data;
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppNavMenuOverlay"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorIconNavMenu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_drawer">

        <View
           android:id="@+id/backgoutd_button_disable_ads"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/background_disable_ads_height"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="?attr/colorDayNightLine" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button_disable_ads"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/error_connect_height"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/disable_ads"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/pro_version_text_size"
            android:background="?android:colorBackground"
            android:onClick="onClickPayDisableAds"/>
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:elevation="4dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="?popupOverlayStyle"
            app:title="@string/label_activity_main"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:elevation="0dp"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_height"
            app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"
            android:background="?attr/colorMainPrimaryDark"
            app:tabTextColor="?android:colorBackground"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="?colorAccent"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

     <include layout="@layout/store" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="@string/ADMOB_BANNER_ID">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Код в студию. Трудно понять, где это у вас упало то

Comment: `MainActivity.java:155` что у вас здесь находится, вы приложили ошибку но не приложили место где она возникает

Comment: так же приложите разметку данной активности

Comment: @Andrew там находится setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: тогда приложите разметку, и код onCreate функции

Comment: @Andrew добавил разметку и код  onCreate();

Comment: @SergeiBuvaka Добавил код